# Usando String de Conexão Dinâmica em Asp.Net Webforms e Windows Forms

Tags: asp.net, winforms, connectionstring

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com **4 camadas** (`Banco`, `RegraNegocio`, `Webforms` e `Windows Forms`).

Fiz as seguintes referências:

> **Webforms** > RegraNegocio > Banco
> **winforms** > RegraNegocio > Banco

Na minha Biblioteca de Classes (*banco*) eu tenho um arquivo chamado:
**config.settings**

Neste arquivo tenho apenas duas propriedades do tipo `string`.

> **strconnection** - onde fica armazenada a conexão.
>
> **infoBanco**     - onde fica armazenado qual banco de dado é, ex: (access, sqlserver, postgre)

Eu atribuo valores para essas propriedades quando o é realizado o login (winforms). Elas funcionam perfeitamente, mas quando fui utilizar em **asp.net** dá um erro, dizendo que não posso usar o `arquivo.settings`.

Mudei o escopo das variáveis de **User** para **application**, porém a execução não permite que eu atribua valores às mesmas em tempo de execução. As propriedades têm apenas `{get;}` quando o escopo é o de aplicação.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer para armazenar a string de conexão? Pois eu acesso um banco de dados onde os cadastros dos clientes estão armazenados, pego a string de conexão dentro da tabela, para depois acessar o banco de dados do respectivo cliente.

Em desktop foi simples: armazenava no **config.settings** e já saáa usando os métodos e classe pois toda vez que mando um comando ele abre a nova conexão utilizando da propriedade **strConnection** que inicializei quando o usuário fez o login.

Comment: A connection string não é armazenada no web.config por padrão?

Comment: mas eu acesso outros bancos, a string não é fixa, eu pego ela em um banco de dados e queria manter ela na minha biblioteca de classe **banco** com o **config.settings** consegui em desktop mas em web eu não sei fazer..

Answer (score 1):

Se você acessar a pasta da sua aplicação web você vai ver que o arquivo `config.settings` não se encontra no diretório da aplicação. Isso acontece porque as referências para os demais projetos são copiadas para a pasta `bin` como *assemblies*, mas os arquivos físicos da dependência não.

Os arquivos devem ser replicados no ambiente web manualmente (sim, você vai ter que criar uma cópia) ou você pode colocar as informações deste arquivo em um [`Resource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx) e ao referenciar o projeto na web ele estará disponível para sua aplicação `Asp.Net`.

Minha dica é criar um link para o arquivo, assim ambos os projetos vão compartilhar um único arquivo (não vai precisar atualizar as informações duas vezes) segue um tutorial de como fazer.

1. Clique com o botão direito do mouse na raiz do seu projeto web e vá em:
   Add > Existing Item > Add as Link (Note que no botão add vai existir uma setinha para baixo. Clique nela para mudar de `Add` para `Add as Link`);
2. Selecione o arquivo `config.settings` existênte no diretório do seu projeto de banco de dados e clique em Ok;
3. Note que um link para o arquivo original será criado, ou seja, ambos os 
   projetos vão partilhar um único arquivo físico;
4. Clique em cima do arquivo linkado na aplicação web e vá em `Properties` > `Copy To Output Directory` e atribua a opção `Copy Always`.

Havendo quaisquer dúvidas, sinta-se a vontade para comentar que vou lhe auxiliando.